# Initial value of time function

Tags: function

I need help find the the initial value for the following time function:
$$F(s) = \frac{10(s+6)}{(s+2)(s+3)} $$

I've found the final value to be \$F(s)=0\$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial Value theorem States that the initial value is given by:

$$
  \lim_{s \rightarrow \infty} sF(s)
$$

so in our case, the initial value, \$f_0\$, is:

$$
 f_0 = \lim_{s \rightarrow \infty}\frac{10s(s+6)}{(s+2)(s+3)} 
$$

$$
  f_0 = \frac{10s^2}{s^2} = 10
$$